# Как переместить курсор в конец input при активации маски?

Tags: javascript, input

Как переместить курсор в конец input при активации маски?

```js
    function maskPhone(selector, masked = '+7 (___) ___-__-__') {
        const elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

        function mask(event) {
            const keyCode = event.keyCode;
            const template = masked,
                def = template.replace(/\D/g, ""),
                val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
            //console.log(template);
            let i = 0,
                newValue = template.replace(/[_\d]/g, function (a) {
                    return i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) || def.charAt(i) : a;
                });
            i = newValue.indexOf("_");
            if (i !== -1) {
                newValue = newValue.slice(0, i);
            }
            let reg = template.substr(0, this.value.length).replace(/_+/g,
                function (a) {
                    return "\\d{1," + a.length + "}";
                }).replace(/[+()]/g, "\\$&");
            reg = new RegExp("^" + reg + "$");
            if (!reg.test(this.value) || this.value.length < 5 || keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) {
                this.value = newValue;
            }
            if (event.type === "blur" && this.value.length < 5) {
                this.value = "";
            }
        }

        for (const elem of elems) {
            elem.addEventListener("input", mask);
            elem.addEventListener("focus", mask);
            elem.addEventListener("blur", mask);
        }
        
    }
    maskPhone('.phone', '+7 (___) ___-__-__');
```

```html
<input type="text" class="phone">
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ переместить курсор в конец инпута - это

```js
setInterval(() => {
  var inp = document.querySelector("input")
  inp.selectionStart = inp.value.length
}, 3000)
```

```html
<input value=1234567890>
```